# How can I run two or more tasks by using just one input statement?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run different commands by only using one user input, in which the program runs a specific task (in this case, Weather or Time check can be run.) and prints a message as well(Depends on the command that was run). In this sample code, I haven't tried to use loop yet to go back to the command1 input so please disregard that.

Here's for the weather:

```
command1 = str(input("Initiate command."))
if command1 in ('Weather', 'I need weather updates', 'Updates about the weather?', 'forecast'):
    print("Give me a couple of minutes.")
```

My problem starts here:

```
if command1 in ['time', 'What is the time?','time and date please.']:
import random
import time

answers_time = [
"This is the current time:\n",
"Time right now is:\n"
]
#THIS PRINTS THE TIME    

print(random.choice(answers_time) + time.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
```

When I type "Time etc." it previews the time correctly, but when I
typed in "forecast or initiate any weather command." it prints (Give
me a couple mins.) < which is correct but, it proceeds with this error

```
   print(random.choice(answers_time) + time.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
NameError: name 'answers_time' is not defined
```

How can I stop the error from occurring? As you can see, `answers_time` is well defined because it is the name of the list where it gets the answers.

All code:

```
command1 = str(input("Initiate command."))

if command1 in ['Weather', 'I need weather updates', 'Updates about the weather?', 'forecast']:
    print("Give me a couple of minutes.") (code for grabbing weather here.)

elif command1 in ['time', 'What is the time?','time and date please.']:

import random
import time

answers_time = [
"This is the current time:\n",
"Time right now is:\n"
]

print(random.choice(answers_time) + time.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for the second command is not indented correctly. you want something like:

```
if command1 in [weather commands]:
    #do weather related stuff
    print(weather output)

elif command1 in [time commands]:
    #do time related stuff
    print(time output)
```

But instead you have:

```
if command1 in [weather commands]:
    #do weather related stuff
    print(weather output)

elif command1 in [time commands]:
    #do time related stuff

print(time output)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know it was that simple. I'm still new to python.